# Getting 404 Error when accessing endpoints in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application where I'm trying to create REST endpoints. However, when I try to access the `/users` or `/test` endpoints, I receive a 404 error. I suspect the issue might be related to the component scanning configuration and the use of `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Here's an overview of my project structure and code:

**BackendApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.kaquya.backend.configs"})
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/users")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.register(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail());
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testEndpoint() {
        return "this is a test endpoint";
    }
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserExtractor userExtractor;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, UserExtractor userExtractor) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userExtractor = userExtractor;
    }

    public User register(String username, String password, String email) {
        User existingUser = userExtractor.findByUsername(username);

        if(existingUser != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Username already exists");
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**UserExtractor**

```
@Repository
public interface UserExtractor {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    User save(User user);
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl**

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Value("${queries.insertUser}")
    private String insertUserQuery;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        String hashedPassword = PasswordHasherService.hashPassword(user.getPassword());

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                insertUserQuery,
                user.getUsername(),
                hashedPassword,
                user.getEmail()
        );

        return user;
    }
}
```

**PropertyConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("queries/user_queries.xml"));
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the `@ComponentScan` annotation in the `BackendApplication` class. Currently, it scans only the `"com.kaquya.backend.configs"` package, which means other components might be ignored. However, when I try to add additional packages to the `@ComponentScan` annotation, I encounter errors related to the queries defined in the `PropertyConfig` class.

I'm using Java Spring Boot v3.1.1, and I'm aware that certain things like `mvcMatchers`, `antMatchers`, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and `authorizeRequests` have been deprecated or removed.

Could you please help me identify the issue and suggest a solution to resolve the 404 error and properly configure component scanning in my Spring Boot application?

Comment: What are you using to test the api? Postman?

Comment: I have tested with both Postman and with a normal .http file.

Comment: Try adding @EnableWebSecurity annotation on security config class

Comment: I have added it, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Disable CSRF, or make sure your token is included in your post request.

Comment: I have disabled csrf in the SecurityConfig, did not fix the issue. Updated original post.

Answer (score -1):

You might use `antMatchers` instead:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                        .antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`requestMatchers` is used when you need some complex matching based on other request conditions like headers, parameters, etc., when `antMatchers` is used to match on the basis of ant-like path patterns

Comment: In Spring Boot 3 and upwards, authorizeRequests is deprecated and therefore I had to find a workaround, which ended up being authorizeHttpRequests and the use of requestMatchers instead of antMatchers or mvcMatchers.

I have tried using antMatchers prior but I am being told that cannot be resolved by my IDE.

Comment: I see, thanks for the addition. It would be great if you could update the original post with a mention of the version you are using, to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: Have you enabled web security in your project?

Comment: changed the original post, completely forgot about the version for some reason.

Comment: yes, I've installed the spring-boot-starter-security and have enabled Web Security in the Application Class.

Answer (score -1):

Put the below annotation on security config :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

For more about spring boot 3, you can visit the below official spring site

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I have already added the annotation to the SecurityConfig while trying to fix the issue, i still receive a 401 Unauthorized error. Updated original post.